# Trouble Removing One Child DIV At A Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a simple Grocery List App and I am having issues trying to remove a place holder div element.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Grocery List App</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="style/form.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="left_side">
            <div id="to_buy">To Buy:</div>
        </div>

        <div id="right_side">
            <div id="in_cart">In Cart:</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="item_body" placeholder="Type Item to Add">

        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/grocery.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    $(function () {
    var rmv = false;
    $('#item_body').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var add = $('#item_body').val();
            $("#to_buy").append('<div class="draggable_item">' + add + '</div>');
            $("#in_cart").append('<div class="holder"></div>'); 
        }
            $(".draggable_item").draggable( {
            axis: "x"
        });

            $(".draggable_item").dblclick(function() {
            this.remove();
            $('#in_cart > div:first').remove();
        });


    });

});
```

CSS

```
    #to_buy {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #00E5EE;

}
#in_cart {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #00E5EE;

}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;

}

#left_side {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    background: #5D5851;
}

#right_side {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #6D5D4D;

}

#item_body {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    color: #326B62;
}


body {
    background: #B1ADA5;
}

.draggable_item {
    color: #FFF;
}

.holder {
   height: 20px;
}
```

So the screen is split vertically between "to_buy" and "in_cart." When I add an item to "to_buy" I also add a "dummy" div to "in_cart" so that the two sides remain even. However, when I double click to remove an item, when

```
$('#in_cart > div:first').remove();
```

gets called, first one div is removed, then on the next double click two, then four etc etc. Apparently, it is getting called multiple times or something else wonky is going wrong.

Comment: because you are setting a dblclick handler every time your keydown handler is called

Comment: you should not use nested handlers like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you bind event handlers for double click event on every Enter key press so they multiply on every item addition. Just move dblclick registration outside:

```
var rmv = false;
$('#item_body').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var add = $('#item_body').val();
        $("#to_buy").append('<div class="draggable_item">' + add + '</div>');
        $("#in_cart").append('<div class="holder"></div>');
    }
    $(".draggable_item").draggable({
        axis: "x"
    });
});

$("#left_side").on("dblclick", ".draggable_item", function () {
    this.remove();
    $('#in_cart > div:first').remove();
});
```

Also note, that it makes sense to delegate double click event to the parent container `#left_side` so you don't have to worry about presence of elements at the time of event registration.

Here is a **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/hx11gkcj/

Comment: Thanks dfsq I really appreciate the quick and accurate help! Cheers!